# Find a number's digits in an arbitrary base

Tags: list-manipulation, number-theory, number-representation, number-bases

I want to write a program in Mathematica which for an input $n$ gives me a representation in a number system of base 26. For example,
$$1419=2\cdot 26^2+2\cdot 26+15.$$

The output I am looking for is the list $\{2,2,15\}$.

Comment: `IntegerDigits[1419, 26]`

Answer (score 4):

Alternatively to `IntegerDigits` you can "write a program" yourself. Something like this will work for positive numbers:

```
sillyIntegerDigits[n_, base_] := First@Transpose@Reverse@Rest@
   NestWhileList[{Mod[#[[2]], base], Floor[#[[2]]/base]} &, {1,n}, #[[2]] > 0&];

sillyIntegerDigits[1419, 26]
(* {2, 2, 15} *)
```